# Displaying the contents of a document file (doc, docx, etc.)

Tags: 7, entities, files

I'm looking for a way to display the contents of an uploaded document file such as a .docx file.

In Drupal 6 I used the [iPaper module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ipaper) which did the trick as all I needed was api code to connect with the service, and the documents were able to be kept private.

But for Drupal 7, I'm pretty sure the [File entity (fieldable files) module](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) should do the trick, but I'm not able to get it working for any files other than .txt.

There are some Google viewer modules which I'm not sure what added functionality they have over the above module, but those don't appear to work correctly. One of them requires that files are public domain which doesn't work for this project due to privacy requirements.

Some other modules like [group docs viewer](https://www.drupal.org/project/groupdocs_viewer) and [ajax docs viewer](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_document_viewer) charge a hefty monthly fee for displaying rendered files, but all I need is a simple open source docx viewer.

What is the best way to proceed?
Which modules are stable for production use?

Best case would allow for user upload, file contents displayed under the actual file attachment, and the rendered document editable for the user.

Note: i've gotten the google docs module to work but that doesn't allow for private files. google needs to access the file publicly in order to render. scribd field also works to some extent but has too many errors and bugs still. looking for a better, simpler solution.

Comment: web publishing != word processing.

Comment: @DavidThomas I dont think that is a fair assssment. I have a lot of arts/museum clients who would benefit from this.  They tend to have lots of documents, but don't always have the manpower to properly adapt them for the web.

Comment: well i've gotten the google docs module to work but that doesn't allow for private files. google needs to access the file publicly in order to render. scribd field also works to some extent but has too many errors and bugs still.  looking for a better, simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this module can be usefull : [Flipping Book](https://www.drupal.org/project/flipping_book)

> This module provides an integration point between Drupal7 and FlippingBook (http://flippingbook.com/).
>   Flippingbook is a very used software to make digital publication from any document you have (.doc, .pdf...).

Answer (score 0):

Try the [PDF Reader](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf_reader) module.

From [this article:](https://www.lifewire.com/choose-a-drupal-module-viewing-pdfs-756633)

> My solution was to use the PDF Reader with the Embed display option. This option would allow me to attach a PDF to a Drupal node, and reliably display it on a Drupal web page.